# Time to ring in the new year with an enchanting puzzle

Tags: rhyme, visual, language, video-games, seasonal

[image: poem]

--This text is 30 characters--

Comment: Are the little grey arrows to the left of the puzzle lines also part of the puzzle/used to solve it?

Comment: @Dorrulf Yes the arrows have meaning.  One thing that is not part of the puzzle, however, is the text to make the post 30 characters long

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answer:

> First off, thank you @NudgeNudge and @Bard !
>  The missing letters are jutrw
>  If we follow the gray arrows for capitalization, we get JuTRw.
>  If we treat this a little like a small imgur-maze, we get:
>  [image: Solution]
>  Pretty cute :) Happy holidays!

Answer (score 12):

Partial:

1st line:

> It is a time of oy and cheer (Skyward Sword alphabet, thanks @Bard!)

2nd line:

> So please lend me yor ear (Fez alphabet rotated 90° right)

3rd line:

> I wan to give you all a gift (Halo Forerunner alphabet)

4th line

> Hury and solve it most swift (Halo Sangheili Covenant alphabet)

5th line

> So e can enjoy it still this year (Standard Galactic Alphabet from Commander Keen)

So:

> The letters J U T R W are missing from those sentences.

Comment: I'm not sure how you figured out the languages, but the `DEAR` was meant to assist in that.  Each letter is in the font of the game logo.  Note that the 5th line is also the language used for enchanting in another game.  Excellent job.

Comment: Yeah @DavidStarkey, I figured that out but it was really hard for me to get the game from just the letter, so I went looking for fictional alphabets until I found the ones that fitted :)

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the first line might translate to something like:

> It is a ti_e __  __  a__ __eer.

based off of the repeated symbol usage and rhyme scheme. Unsure of what alphabet it is using.

With some guessing that doesn't really fit:

> Maybe something like "It is a time of love and cheer"?

EDIT:

> Looks like the skyward sword alphabet and the translation then is "IT IS A TIME OF OY AND CHEER"